# php 1 is a string not integer

Tags: php

I'm using a GET variable and people get to it by the following URL:

```
page?siteID=1
```

and I check to make sure that siteID is an integer, but PHP is saying it is a string.

How can I convert it to a integer? I noticed that `intval()` would convert 0x1A to 26, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: old PHP trick $id = 0 + $_GET['siteID']; some hate it, some love it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to convert the variable, but simply check if it represents a number, you can also use the [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/is_numeric) function. Either that, or you can use the conversion methods as described in other answers, whichever suits your particular need best.

**EDIT:** based on James Socol's comment, it may also be worth looking at the [`ctype_digit`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) function. For your particular application (it looks like you want to check for some page ID number), this might be better suited than the `is_numeric` function.

Comment: Be aware that `is_numeric("-1.23e25")` will evaluate to true. `ctype_digit` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @James Socol - I didn't know that function, looks like it might be a better candidate for this particular application. Thanks James, I have updated my answer in reponse to your comment.

Comment: @James Socol - Thanks Never seen that before, is_numeric should be fine though. I'm just using it to make sure the input it numbers only, then I check it against a numeric field in my database.

Answer (score 9):

Just as a side note, so that you know *why* this is happening, here's what's going on.

When a web browser sends a `GET` request, it's all text. The URL `http://example.com/page?siteID=1' is actually sent as a single string; in the HTTP request it will be this line:

```
GET /page?siteID=1 HTTP/1.0
```

(The "`http://example.com`" part was used by the web browser to figure out which server to talk to, and what network protocol to use.)

PHP gets hold of that and does a whole bunch of work for you to parse it. It splits it into three pieces based on those spaces (method "`GET`", URI "`/page?siteID=1`" and protocol "`HTTP/1.1`"), and further parses the URI into a path ("`/page`") and query parameters ("siteID=1"), which it further parses into name/value pairs. And even that whole `GET` line quoted above was only part of the full text stream delivered to the HTTP server as a request.

So you're seeing the the result of a whole lot of work to convert a longish sequence of characters into a lot of different pieces.

If you're really curious, you can use tools such as Wireshark or the Firefox [Live HTTP Headers plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) to see the details of what text strings are actually passing over the network. It's worth learning, if you're a web developer.

Answer (score 5):

Either cast to int

```
$id = (int)$_GET['siteID'];
```

knowing the rules on [string-to-integer conversions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Or use

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['siteID'])) { //...
```

If you want to be sure it only contains numbers (characters 0-9). If you want it to be a numeric string, including "-1.35e+105" you could use `is_numeric()`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to cast it to an int

e.g.

$siteid = (int) $_GET['siteID'];

That will do it.

Comment: hmm... can't seem to find the docs for that, what does (int) do if there are non-numeric characters?

Comment: PHP is a dynamic type Language so it assumes your GET variable is a string.  there are many ways to change the assumed type. In programming its called casting. 

Or as they state in the PHP manual Type Juggling
http://ie.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 2):

try [is_numeric() function](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Answer (score 1):

what you could do; ctype_digit($_GET['siteID'])

Answer (score 0):

All parameter values are strings. You must explicitly convert from string to integer. You can cast as suggested in other answers or use [setType(var, type)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) where type is "integer"

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['siteID'];
  settype($id, "integer");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP treats all GET/POST/COOKIE variables as strings until you do something with them.

Here is a good PHP.net reference for you to look at:
http://ca.php.net/language.types.type-juggling

Answer (score 0):

Php is weakly typed. For him, integer and string can threated the same way, it will jus try to guess how according to the context.

Anyway, when you pass a variable with GET, it's always a string because the HTTP protocole is all about text.

So two things :

- you, most of the time, don't need to check if it's an integer. Use duck typing : if it's a string that looks like an integer enought, use it directly.
- if you really want to check, use is_numeric().
- if you need a conditional statement, using == to check a string against an integer will work. If you want to check with a type enforcement, use ===.

The fudgy way of managing variables is part of what makes PHP, well, PHP. Love it, or hate it, but don't try code in PHP like in JAVA or C#.

Answer (score 0):

More ideas:

```
$isInt = ($_GET['id'] == (int)$_GET['id']); // not strict comparing!
$isInt2 = preg_match('/\-?[0-9]+/', $_GET['id']);
```

and finally a safe way to get the $id:

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] == (int)$_GET['id'])) 
    ? (int)$_GET['id'] 
    : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using mod_rewrite (if available) and regular expressions to obfuscate and secure your GET variables instead of casting them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The URI path `page?siteID=1` is a string; The value of `$_GET['siteID']` will originally be a string.

Assumption: the `siteID` value is used to look in a dB table by the `siteID` field so a valid `siteID` value must look like an integer greater than zero.

`is_numeric()` is not enough in this case unfortunately because `is_numeric('7e2')` returns true.

You want to validate the string value of `siteID` as an integer without casting any value from $_GET, keeping your $_GET with raw values because you might need them later.

```
function is_valid_id($id) {
    return strval($id) === strval(intval($id)) && $id > 0;
}

if (is_valid_id($_GET['siteID']))
    $siteID = intval($_GET['siteID']);
    # Value is ready to be processed as integer
else
    # Refresh page with invalid id error message
```

It renders invalid '0', '0.0', '-0', '07', '-09', '0y', '7e2', '-w', '-b.9', 'G98', '-h7', '98R', '98.7', '98,8', '0x1A', '\x1A', '5+5', '5*5', etc.