# Laravel: Request data is supposed to be integers but show up as string

Tags: php, laravel, postman

This are the parameters I pass as POST request from postman
[image: This are the parameters I pass as POST request from postman]

When $request is returned from the method. All integer gets converted to string.

```
public function update(Request $request){
    return $request;
}
```

Received response is as follows:
[image: response image]

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about your request. What is your `Content-Type` for both request and response?

Comment: Content-Type is application/json

Comment: Postman probably doesn't know the data type of the request variables.

Comment: HTTP is a text protocol, everything is a string.  There are many questions here describing this already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502854/is-int-and-get-or-post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873838/input-type-number-is-returning-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779402/why-are-integers-becoming-strings-when-i-post-using-jquery-ajax-to-a-php-script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897974/php-1-is-a-string-not-integer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837558/testing-if-php-string-is-an-integer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14960305/6089612 ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is\_int and GET or POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502854/is-int-and-get-or-post)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 9.32 brings a handy shorthand function for casting request values to integer (and float):

```
$request->integer('some_int_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to an integer; please try the following.

```
(int)$request->visitor_count;
```

or

```
(int)request()->get('visitor_count');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

intval($yourvalue)

Comment: Use of undefined constant intval - assumed 'intval' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'visitor_count', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`

Comment: for how many request you would manually filter.. the datatype in the laravel request shouldn't change.

Comment: But you're probably already passing it as a string. See my comment under the question.

Comment: no I have passed an integer clearly. Not only to postman. when i use Retrofit API to call this API, it also converting to string, where retrofit passes data with data-types

Comment: Can you access the raw request payload?

Comment: To avoid this answer being deleted, try to [edit] it into an answer instead of a question...